# What's the equivalent of `width: max(100%, fit-content)`?

Tags: css

I would like my div to fit the size of it's content if the size of parent div is smaller than content,
and be the size of parent otherwise.

I can do the 1st by `width: fit-content`,
and the 2nd by `width: 100%`,

and I wanted to join this together by `width: max(100%, fit-content)`,
but seems like this is not working.

Any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: max-width:100%;width:fit-content ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope, this behaves equal to `max-width: 100%`, which behaves equal to `width: 100%`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Didn't see your comment before adding my answer

Comment: @pbialy no it won't, test and see

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just tested :) Why would I write this without testing.

Comment: then you didn't test correctly or you have something else creating the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/4cvu56pq/

Comment: I would rather say - your answer might work in some cases, but not in all cases. So it's not the answer to my question.

Comment: you should make your question clear enough and precise *your* specific case. There is no answer that work in all the cases, that's simply impossible.

Comment: If I would want answer for "specific" case then I would ask "specific" question. I wanted a "general" answer, so I've asked "general" question. Your answer was not "general". It was ok in some "specific" case which you've created. That's not what I wanted. And the fact that your answer is not "general" doesn't mean that 'There is no answer that work in all the cases'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the max between 100% and fitting the content, you should instead set the minumum width of the your `<div>` to the size of its parent. I was able to reporoduce what you were asking for by setting the container in question (blue box in the example below) to be an `inline-block` with min width of 100% under its parent (red box in the example below).

This way, the container always takes 100% of its parent until you resize the parent to be smaller than the inner content, in that case, the container doesn't shrink past the content and so the parent (red box) has to scroll.

This works with the display property as `flex` and `inline-block`, but not with `block`, maybe someone here can explain why.

Here is the example, I made the parent (red box) resizable so you can see the solution in action:

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block; /* or flex */
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: lightGrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">For blue box, max is at red box and min is at content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like in the case I have in my code I need both `min-width: 100%` and `width: fit-content`, and this solves my problem. Thanks for answer, smart and simple one :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
width: max(100%, fit-content);
```

is equivalent to

```css
width: fit-content;
min-width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum width of an element with `max-width`

```css
.container{
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.content{
  width:200px;
  max-width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: this doesn't help in my case, but answer from @Ghassen Louhaichi works